# Finding the "maximum" or "minimum" color in a list of colors?

Tags: c#, list, graphics, colors, bitmap

I have a list of default C# objects. They are all in the RGB format, meaning, for black, for example, looks like this `0, 0, 0`. Is it possible to find the "maximum" and "minimum" value of this list? What I mean is, find the least intense or most intense color in this list of colors, kinda like a `list.Maximum` in a list of integers. Trying to Google didn't give me anything, and trying to use Intellisense only gave me these options:

[image]

Comment: Are they IComparable?

Comment: Sorry sir, I'm not quite sure what that means.

Comment: Do the C# Objects in your list implement the `System.IComparable` interface?

Comment: I'm not sure.. How do I find out?

Comment: You can easily accomplish your goal with LINQ however you don't provide a definition for greater than or less than which makes your problem impossible to answer. How do you want to compare for equality? Btw `IComparible` is an interface that methods like `OrderBy` can take an instance of and use as the rules for comparison when ordering a list.

Comment: Heh, I understand comparing colors is a bit hard; a bit harder than comparing integers. I am thinking the experts here would have a better idea than me haha.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage it really isn't, the problem is you haven't said HOW you intend to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you calculate this value for each color and take the color with the highest value it will be your result:

```
var intensity = (0.2125 * R) + (0.7154 * G) + (0.0721 * B);
```

With a list of `Color` objects find the max like so:

```
var cs = new List<Color> { Color.Red, Color.Black };
var max = cs.OrderByDescending(x => (0.2125 * x.R) + (0.7154 * x.G) + (0.0721 * x.B)).First();
```

Comment: Would I create a method that loops through the entire list, converts each to intensity values, and then find the max?

Comment: Hey doorstuck - I am getting a red underline under `Max()` like this: http://puu.sh/6fhR5/0efde4bbbb.png

Comment: Put this in the top of your file: 

using System.Linq;

Comment: Thanks for helping! Looks like after finding this value I still need to correspond to which color it is referring to.

Comment: Sorry. Look at the solution now. If you need to calculate this very often consider saving the sorted list of results for future lookup.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution was of so much help, and introduced me to my first LINQ statement in C#.

Comment: Great. You will learn to love LINQ. It can be hard to grasp the concepts of lazy evaluation but you will learn it.

Comment: Sorry for being so questioning and you don't have to reply if you don't want to - but how do I find the minimum? Thank you!

Comment: Note that sorting will be less efficient than an algorithm that requires a single pass. As you use LINQ more, knowing various operations' performance characteristics can be important.

Comment: I agree with @dahlbyk. Use LINQ with care. You might want to save the sorted list of intensities for later use: `var intensities = cs.OrderByDescending(x => (0.2125 * x.R) + (0.7154 * x.G) + (0.0721 * x.B)).ToList()` then later on you can ask for `intensities.First()` and `intensities.Last()` without calculating and sorting everything twice.

Comment: In fact from the small screenshot you provided it could look like this code is running as part of a draw pass? If so consider calculating the list outside the drawing methods and just refer to the list in the draw methods.

Answer (score 0):

[Interactive Extensions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ix-main) (and several other libraries) include a `MaxBy()` function that would let you find the color with the maxiumum value of the specified function.

For example, to find the most blue color in the list:

```
// Update: Forgot MaxBy returns a list of all elements with the max value
var bluest = colors.MaxBy(c => c.B)[0];
```

Or if you don't want to use their implementation, you can implement `MaxBy()` in terms of `Aggregate()`:

```
public static T MaxBy<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, R> selector)
    where R : IComparable
{
    return seq.Aggregate((x, y) =>
                         selector(x).CompareTo(selector(y)) < 0 ? y : x);
}
```

If `seq` is large, this will perform better than sorting, which is `O(n lg n)`.

Comment: Since this is a plugin that works in a piece of software called Grasshopper 3D, I would like to avoid external libraries. But - thanks for the suggestion! If I run out of options I will use this.

Comment: Ix is open source, so you could borrow (with attribution!) their implementation: http://rx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/EnumerableEx.Aggregates.cs

Comment: While I like this more than the LINQ to Objects equivalent you could just use it if you don't want a 3rd party lib.

Comment: This might be overkill. Just use System.Linq extension methods.

Comment: The built-in methods make it easy to find the max value, but the question is to find the element with the maximum value. Thus `MaxBy()`.